# How to make ArrayList that work as two dimentional array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to make arrayList object in java that work as two dimentional array. My question is how can we access value from specific dimention from arrayList.

in two dimentional array, if i want to access value then it can be as m[i][j].

But in arraylist how can i do that ?

Comment: Where is your code and what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Probably nested lists `List<List<T>>` and `outter.get(i).get(j)` ...

Comment: I just want to know how to work with ArrayList if i want to treat them as a two dimensional array

Comment: And exactly that's what A4L wrote before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like a `List` in a `List`??

May be something like...

```
List<List<...>> twoDList = new ArrayList<>();
```

> i want to make a List, in which each List key contains another List inside it

It should more like you want some kind of `Map`, which is basically a key/value pair.

```
Map<String, List<String>> mapValues = new HashMap<>(25);
List<String> listOfValues = ...;
//...
mapValues.put("A unique key for this list", listOfValues);

//...

List<String> thatListOfValues = mapValues.get("A unique key for this list");
```

Comment: yes brother, i want to make a List, in which each List key contains another List inside it.

Comment: Have you thought of using a `Map` instead?

Answer (score 2):

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
list.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
list.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
list.get(0).add(5);
list.get(1).add(6);

for(List<Integer> listiter : list)
{
    for(Integer integer : listiter)
    {
        System.out.println("" + integer);
    }
}
```

This way you can get the items like

```
list.get(1).get(0); //second dimension list -> integer
```

EDIT:

Although it is true that you can use a Map if you are trying to use numeric indices for example for each list, like so:

```
Map<Integer, List<YourObject>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<YourObject>>();
map.put(0, new ArrayList<YourObject>());
map.put(5, new ArrayList<YourObject>());
map.get(0).add(new YourObject("Hello"));
map.get(5).add(new YourObject("World"));

for(Integer integer : map.keySet())
{
    for(YourObject yourObject : map.get(integer))
    {
         yourObject.print(); //example method
         System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

Although even then the accessing of Lists would be the same as before,

```
map.get(0).get(1); //List -> value at index
```

Obviously you don't need to use Integers as the generic type parameter, that's just a placeholder type.

Answer (score 1):

Memory is an important consideration here.

It *can* be acceptable to model a 2D (or higher dimension) array using a 1D container. (This is how the VARIANT SAFEARRAY of Microsoft's COM works.) *But*, consider this carefully if the number of elements is large; especially if the container allocates a contiguous memory block. Using something like `List<List<...` will model a jagged-edged matrix and can fragment your memory.

With the 1D approach, you can use the `get(index)` method on the `ArrayList` appropriately transformed:

Given the (i)th row and (j)th column, transform using `index = i * rows + j` where `rows` is the number of rows in your matrix.

Comment: I think this solution will helpful. I will try this and let u know about its result

Answer (score 1):

The solution like `List<List<..>>` is slow then you should use one dimention array like

```
    // Two dimentions: m and n

        List<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>(m*n);
        for (int i=0; i< m; ++i) {
           for (int j=0; j<n; ++j) {
             String str=arr.get(i*n + j);
             //You code here
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

An arraylist is not an object to make a 2 dimentional arrays. However you can use it anyway :
You can use :

```
new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>; //or
new ArrayList<Object[]>;
```

But you should implement your own matrix class because you will probably have some check to do and a function `get(int row, int column)` would be cool

Answer (score 0):

Also consider [`Table`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) collection provided by Google Guava library. [`ArrayTable`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayTable.html) is an implementation based on 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

You cane define like this

1>

```
List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
```

Fetching

```
list.get(i)[j];
```

2>

```
List<Map<Integer,Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<Integer,Object>>();
```

Fetching

```
list.get(i).get(j);
```