# How to create matrix from java vector of vectors (Multidimentional Vector)

Tags: java, vector

am trying to create vector of Vectors(2d) in java like multidimensional array. then to assign values to specific position in that matrix like what we do using matrix[i][j] in 2D array
Any help.

My data in one Vector:

`n = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g , h]`

I want to create 2D Vector to represent
vector m =

- a b c d
- e f g h

Comment: What type are you trying to store in the Vector? If you're looking for the syntax of a multi-dimensional array, it's `int[][] array = new int[5][6];`

Comment: i know how to work with multi-dimentional array. What i need is to g´creat matrix above using 2D vector and how to assign values in sppecific index.

Comment: You assign new values using `array[2][3] = 6;` for example. Please note that arrays in Java are indexed from zero (so in case of an [5][6] array, the valid indices are [0..4][0..5])

Comment: i know in array i want to implement in vector.

Comment: oh you mean THAT kind of Vector. The lack of capital letters on the class name really confused me! In that case, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526019/how-to-make-arraylist-that-work-as-two-dimentional-array-in-java/24526104#24526104

Comment: Yes i meant Vector...sorry for the confusion. And your suggestion link is ArrayList but my problem is to use Vector of Vectors or in other words 2D vectors please help.

Comment: Vectors work pretty much exactly the same way as ArrayLists, so eh.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a 2D Vector using the following:

```
Vector<Vector<Integer>> vector2D = new Vector<Vector<Integer>>(10);
```

This will create a Vector of size 10 which will contain Vectors with Integer(Vector) values.
Before setting a value at a particular index, you need to create a Vector of Integer and set at the row position(2 in your case).

```
vector2D.add(2, new Vector<Integer>(10));
```

You can then set a value at the column index using the following syntax:

```
Vector<Integer> rowVector = vector2D.get(2);
rowVector.add(3, 5);
```

Here we first get the Vector of Integers (Vector) at index 2. Then add the value at the index 3 in the Vector of Integers(Vector).

Hope this explains.

Comment: thank you for this solution but still i need some explanation if you can show me conversion of this matrix[2][3]= 5 which means assigning 5 at the row index 2 and column index 3 or some example tutorial i tried to check online different sites i didnt manage to find good solution please! @priyesh

Comment: can i get your contacts please so as we can chat and you can help me out of this problem. @ Priyesh

Comment: @AllyBitebo, I have created a chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56951/matrix-creation in case you want to discuss this.

Comment: thank you for your help i managed to do it. sorry for the late reply

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if it helped? Or add your implementation to the question, so that it can be useful for others.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reasons, [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) bumped your question just a couple minutes ago. In 2021 you probably would not use `Vector` any more, but `List`. Actually both of them have [`subList(start,end)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#subList(int,%20int)) method (even in Java 7 what the link points to), so practically you would just loop over vector/list in row-sized steps and use this method.
Also, you might fancy using streams so instead of initializing the result variable in a separate line, the stream collector does that for you:

```
List<Integer> vector=Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
int rowSize=4;
List<List<Integer>> matrix=IntStream.range(0, vector.size()/rowSize)
        .mapToObj(row->vector.subList(row*rowSize, (row+1)*rowSize))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(matrix);
```

will output `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]`.

Also, as `Vector` can be constructed from `List`, after all you can do that too:

```
Vector<Integer> vector=new Vector<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8));
int rowSize=4;
Vector<Vector<Integer>> matrix=new Vector<Vector<Integer>>(
        IntStream.range(0, vector.size()/rowSize)
        .mapToObj(row->new Vector<Integer>(vector.subList(row*rowSize, (row+1)*rowSize)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
System.out.println(matrix);
```

And of course in the background both of them do pretty much the same as a `for` loop would have done:

```
Vector<Integer> vector=new Vector<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8));
int rowSize=4;
Vector<Vector<Integer>> matrix=new Vector<Vector<Integer>>();
for(int row=0;row<vector.size()/rowSize;row++)
    matrix.add(new Vector<Integer>(vector.subList(row*rowSize, (row+1)*rowSize)));
System.out.println(matrix);
```