# Adding a new cell to a matrix dynamically in java

Tags: java, dynamic, matrix, arraylist

I need to add dynamically a cell to a matrix or an Object[][] to be more precise, the size of the Object's columns is 2 and the rows need to grow every time i need to add an entry.

I found this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5061736/3610008) but the problem is that it handles a one dimensional arraylist, and i don't how to handle a two dimensional arraylist.

So the question exactly is: How can i add dynamicaly and in ascending order a row to an matrix of Objects or to an arraylist?

Any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't use arrays, but use `List`s, for example, here you may use `ArrayList<Object[]>` or (better) `ArrayList<Column> columns;`, where `Column` is a class, which contains these two items.

Comment: "the size of the Object's columns is 2 and the rows need to grow every time i need to add an entry." I don't understand this.

Comment: @aliteralmind this would make sense, when you change rows with cols and vice-versa.

Comment: You should look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526019/how-to-make-arraylist-that-work-as-two-dimentional-array-in-java/24526104#24526104

Answer (score 2):

It works the same way as the answer you referenced, only you would have two nested arraylists as such:

```
List<List<Item>> matrix = new ArrayList<List<Item>>();
```

To get one dimension, just do:

```
matrix.get(x);
```

To get the second one, just do:

```
matrix.get(x).get(y);
```

To add, you can just add "rows":

```
matrix.add(new ArrayList<Item>());
```

If your second dimension is static, an easier route would just be to do:

```
List<Object[]> matrix;
```

But this would mean you need a set size for the Object[] array.

Comment: Why not `List<List<Items>> arrayList = new ArrayList<List<Items>>();` ?

Comment: Works as well, just used a specific implementation as an example.

Comment: I think, `Item` is more correct example-name, than `Items` here.

Comment: Updated answer as per suggestions

Comment: Oh wait, after the last edit your answer contain the mistake, it didn't before: `ArrayList<ArrayList<Item>` IS NOT `List<List<Item>`. So, either it should be `ArrayList<List<Item>` at the right side (preferrable) or `List<ArrayList<Item>>` at the right side. For the explanation look @ http://www.coderanch.com/t/591388/java/java/Covariance-Contravariance-Invariance

Comment: For the List<Object[]> lets say i want to access the cell {3, 1}, do i do matrix.get(3)[1]?

Comment: Remember that indices start at 0. {x, y} would be matrix.get(x)[y-1] (this is assuming your matrix starts at 1). Also remember to initialize and add the array before indexing or you will get null pointer exceptions.